# When can IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext be null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpcontext

The docs for `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` [say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor.httpcontext#definition):

> Returns null if there is no active HttpContext.

Similar questions involve getting nulls due to misconfiguration. In my system it's never been null (so far).

When is it possible that there is no active context, and thus the property would be null?

Comment: Outside of a request, I imagine it would be `null`.

Comment: When there is no active HTTP request in scope, obviously. That can happen for pretty much any background task

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#httpcontext-access-from-a-background-thread

Comment: Thanks. Are there any other cases you could think of - I suppose hosted services would be in the same category.

Comment: `I suppose hosted services would be in the same category. `Yes,I think it also belongs to background task.